# Combining three very similar queries? (Postgres)

Tags: postgresql

So I have three queries. I'm trying to combine them all into one query. Here they are with their outputs:

Query 1:

```
SELECT distinct on (name) name, count(distinct board_id)
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN table_b on tablea.id = table_b.id 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Output:

```
A | 15
B | 26
C | 24
D | 11
E | 31
F | 32
G | 16
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT  distinct on (name) name, count(board_id) as total
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN table_b on tablea.id = table_b.id 
GROUP BY 1, board_id
ORDER BY name, total DESC
```

Output:

```
A | 435
B | 246
C | 611
D | 121
E | 436
F | 723
G | 293
```

Finally, the last query:

```
SELECT  distinct on (name) name, count(board_id) as total
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN table_b on tablea.id = table_b.id 
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY name, total DESC
```

Output:

```
A | 14667
B | 65123
C | 87426
D | 55198
E | 80612
F | 31485
G | 43392
```

Is it possible to format it to be like this:

```
A | 15 | 435 | 14667
B | 26 | 246 | 65123
C | 24 | 611 | 87426
D | 11 | 121 | 55198
E | 31 | 436 | 80612
F | 32 | 723 | 31485
G | 16 | 293 | 43392
```

EDIT:

With @Clodoaldo Neto 's help, I combined the first and the third queries with this:

```
SELECT name, count(distinct board_id), count(board_id) as total
FROM tablea
INNER JOIN table_b on tablea.id = table_b.id
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY description ASC
```

The only thing preventing me from combining the second query with this new one is the `GROUP BY` clause needing `board_id` to be in it. Any thoughts from here?

Comment: What's that `board_id` column in the `GROUP BY` clause of the second query?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I slightly edited two of the queries. I replaced the `*` wildcard with `board_id` and it gives the same output. Does this help any?

Comment: Notice that `distinct on` has no effect on the first and third queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hard to get right without test data. But here is my try:

```
with s as (
    select name, grouping(name, board_id) as grp,
        count(distinct board_id) as dist_total,
        count(*) as name_total,
        count(*) as name_board_total
    from
        tablea
        inner join
        table_b on tablea.id = table_b.id
    group by grouping sets ((name), (name, board_id))
)
select name, dist_total, name_total, name_board_total
from
    (
        select name, dist_total, name_total
        from s
        where grp = 1
    ) r
    inner join
    (
        select name, max(name_board_total) as name_board_total
        from s
        where grp = 0
        group by name
    ) q using (name)
order by name
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS